# Как преобразовать строки в число, вычислить квадратный корень и округлить итоговое значение?

Tags: java, строки, числа

Надо принять целочисленное число типа `long` в строковом виде, преобразовывать его в тип `long`, вычислить из него квадратный корень, и округлить получившееся значение до ближайшего `long`.

Правильно ли я реализовал это? Вот мой код:

```
public static long parseAndSqrt(String number) {
    long lo = Long.parseLong(number);
    long l = (long) Math.sqrt(lo);
    return Math.round(l);
}
```

Comment: Нет. У вас получится округление вниз, а не к ближайшему.

Comment: Дело не в округлении. `(long) Math.sqrt(lo);` уже возвращает целое, отбрасывая дробную часть.

Comment: Ну и `Math.round` тут не делает ничего вообще.

Comment: @Mbo не заметил, спасибо что поправили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, это не совсем правильно, поскольку приведение вещественного числа к целому просто отбрасывает его дробную часть, а не округляет по правилам математики. Например, такой код

```
System.out.println((int)3.99);
```

выведет на экран 3.

Поэтому чтобы ваш код работал так, как вы хотите, исправить его нужно следующим образом:

```
public static long parseAndSqrt(String number) {
    long lo = Long.parseLong(number);
    double l = Math.sqrt(lo);
    return Math.round(l);
}
```

Можно заметить, что здесь объявляется пара не совсем нужных переменных. В принципе, код можно записать в одну строку:

```
public static long improvedParseAndSqrt(String number) {
    return Math.round(Math.sqrt(Long.parseLong(number)));
}
```